# Drawing coordinate system and some shape

Tags: java, eclipse

Write a program that draws the coordinate system and some geometric shapes on the console
screen as described below.
Ask the user to select one of the following shapes:

1. Rectangle
2. Triangle

Triangle -> If the user selects to draw a triangle, ask for the coordinates of the three vertices
vertex 1 (a, b), vertex 2 (c, d), and vertex 3 (e, f) that describe the triangle.

Rectangle -> If the user selects to draw a rectangle, ask for the coordinates of the three
vertices vertex 1 (a, b), vertex 2 (c, d), and vertex 3 (e, f) that describe the rectangle. Vertex 2 and vertex 3 are in the neighborhood of vertex 1, and vertex 4 is in the opposite of vertex 1, i.e. the first diagonal is between vertex 1 and vertex 4, and the second one is between vertex 2 and vertex 3. You will the coordinates of vertex 4 using the information for other vertices. Also, you will check whether the points given construct a rectangle; if not, you will notice the user and will not the the rectangle.

It's task. I should use loops. I have tried to find equations of two points using slope. I need to get more cleverly solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to find equations of two points using slope

### Finding a point `(x, y)` on a line with a slope `m`

---

**Finding `y` with a known `x`:** `y = m * x`
**Finding `x` with a known `x`:** `x = y / m`

Instead of checking if a point `(x, y)` is on a line, we could calculate the point given `x` or `y`.